# what does the cover page of Guyon and Labordere's Nonlinear Option Pricing represent?

Tags: stochastic-processes, pricing, models, books, nonlinear

It could be a bit offtopic, but I don't see the link between the contents of the book and the cover page.
Thanks

[image: book cover page]

Comment: It looks to me like a contour line graph for a (highly nonlinear) function of two variables. But what it has to do with options I don't know.

Comment: I dropped one of the authors an e-mail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Julien Guyon was so kind as to explain the story behind the cover and gave me permission to share it with the rest of the community:

> There's no direct link between the contents of the book and the cover
> page. I love [Josef Albers'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Albers) art and we decided to choose one of Albers'
> artworks to illustrate the cover page. The lithograph somehow suggests
> nonlinearity, as it evokes level sets of a nonlinear function, so we
> thought it would fit well---and also fit well with the black, white,
> and red style of the covers of this book series.
>
> The artwork is [Graphic Tectonic by Josef Albers (1941)](https://www.wikiart.org/en/josef-albers/graphic-tectonic-1941). It was
> actually inspired by pre-Columbian archaeological sites that Albers
> visited in Mexico. This is well explained and illustrated in the
> superb book [Josef Albers in Mexico](https://www.guggenheim.org/exhibition/josef-albers-in-mexico). It is a funny coincidence that the
> quant.stackexchange.com message was posted on Saturday, as I went to
> the Albers and Morandi exhibition at the David Zwirner gallery in New
> York City precisely that day and thought again about the book cover!

Comment: Haha great story overall!

Comment: The work itself is Prefatio (Preface) (1942). The graphic tectonic is a serie of works. It is at the MOMA https://www.moma.org/collection/works/65883?artist_id=97&page=1&sov_referrer=artist

Answer (score 1):

This book aims to demonstrate advanced numerical methods for solving high-dimensional nonlinear PDEs, which do often arise in option pricing. Hence, the authors present general mathematical tools which could be applied to solve these nonlinear (parabolic) PDEs.

The price of a European option under the Black-Scholes model is governed by a linear second order PDE, for which even an analytical solution exists. However, many factors, such as uncertain volatilities or market anomalies, to name just a few, or the calibration of local stochastic volatility/correlation models, lead to nonlinear parabolic PDEs. For these problems, an analytical solution does not exist.

To me, the graph on the cover thus represents such a highly nonlinear function (as @noob2 already pointed out) which eventually could be approximated using one of the numerical methods presented in this book.

**Edit**:
To answer @noob2's question in the comment section, the Feyman-Kac formula is the link between PDEs and stochastic processes. This formula shows that the solution of a parabolic PDE can be represented as a conditional expectation (see this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)). Since all options (with some exceptions) depend on the time to maturity, they are modelled by parabolic PDEs (containing partial derivatives in time), which model a variety of time-dependent phenomena, see the [Heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) for example. Note that the Black-Scholes PDE by the way is a small variant of the Heat equation. Because of the aforementioned factors, many real-world problems in QuantFinance are not linear, they are modelled by high-dimensional nonlinear parabolic PDEs. Finding a solution to these kind of problems is the main concern of this book.